# react-native-calendars calendar height doesn't change

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using react-native-calendars to display a calendar on my project. However, I am not able to change its height. It changes the height of the gray border but not where the days are displayed.

This is the original code:

```
<SafeAreaView>
            <Calendar
                // Specify style for calendar container element. Default = {}
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    height: 100
                }}
                // Specify theme properties to override specific styles for calendar parts. Default = {}
                theme={{
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                    calendarBackground: '#ffffff',
                    textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
                    textSectionTitleDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
                    selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#00adf5',
                    selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
                    todayTextColor: '#00adf5',
                    dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
                    textDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
                    dotColor: '#00adf5',
                    selectedDotColor: '#ffffff',
                    arrowColor: 'orange',
                    disabledArrowColor: '#d9e1e8',
                    monthTextColor: 'blue',
                    indicatorColor: 'blue',
                    textDayFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                    textMonthFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                    textDayHeaderFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                    textDayFontWeight: '300',
                    textMonthFontWeight: 'bold',
                    textDayHeaderFontWeight: '300',
                    textDayFontSize: 16,
                    textMonthFontSize: 16,
                    textDayHeaderFontSize: 16
                }}
                />
        </SafeAreaView>
```

Also, tried to override its style adding to its theme

```
'stylesheet.day.basic':{
            'base':{
              width:30,
              height:50,
              backgroundColor:'pink'
            }
          }
```

[https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/calendar/day/basic/style.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHVqp.png)

But nothing works. Does anybody have an idea on how can I solve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHVqp.png)

Comment: Please add a description of what the image is

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the Calendar with a View and apply the height to the view. Try this:

```
<View style={styles.calendarWrapper}>
    <Calendar
                    // Specify style for calendar container element. Default = {}
                    style={{
                        borderWidth: 5,
                        borderColor: 'gray',
                        height: 100
                    }}
                    // Specify theme properties to override specific styles for calendar parts. Default = {}
                    theme={{
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        calendarBackground: '#ffffff',
                        textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
                        textSectionTitleDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
                        selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#00adf5',
                        selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
                        todayTextColor: '#00adf5',
                        dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
                        textDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
                        dotColor: '#00adf5',
                        selectedDotColor: '#ffffff',
                        arrowColor: 'orange',
                        disabledArrowColor: '#d9e1e8',
                        monthTextColor: 'blue',
                        indicatorColor: 'blue',
                        textDayFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                        textMonthFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                        textDayHeaderFontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold',
                        textDayFontWeight: '300',
                        textMonthFontWeight: 'bold',
                        textDayHeaderFontWeight: '300',
                        textDayFontSize: 16,
                        textMonthFontSize: 16,
                        textDayHeaderFontSize: 16
                    }}
                    />
</View>
```

And make sure to create View wrapper style. Import StyleSheet from 'react-native':

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   calendarWrapper:{
      height: 1000
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste the opening of SafeAreaView. But I have tested with View and doing what you suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I needed to override a couple of styles on the following files:
https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/calendar/day/period/style.js

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/calendar/header/style.js

Basically, on header needed to reduce the font size. If using period, you also will need to play with fontSizes and period height because it is hardcoded on 34.

To override the component's original style:

```
<Calendar theme={{
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                    'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
                         monthText: {
                                   fontSize: 10,
                                   fontFamily: 'Montserrat-bold',
                                   margin: 10
                         }
                    }
                 }
   />
```